# GitHub Actions: Cache Maven .m2 repository on Windows environment C\:\\Users\runneradmin\\.m2\repository: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: java, windows, maven, caching, github-actions

[As the docs state](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven#caching-dependencies) in order to cache the Maven dependencies with GitHub Actions all we have to use is the [actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) action like this:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Set up JDK 1.8
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 1.8
  - name: Cache Maven packages
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: ~/.m2
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
  - name: Build with Maven
    run: mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots verify
```

However using the `windows-2016` GitHub Actions environment, this doesn't provides us with a working cache - [as the logs states](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/runs/2225817750?check_suite_focus=true):

```
Post job cleanup.
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe" --posix --use-compress-program "zstd -T0" -cf cache.tzst -P -C D:/a/spring-boot-admin/spring-boot-admin --files-from manifest.txt --force-local
/usr/bin/tar: C\:\\Users\runneradmin\\.m2\repository: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Warning: Tar failed with error: The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the path to the Maven repository isn't correctly initialized. As [this issue describes](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/632) the paths are written with `\\` instead of `/` which GNU tar expects. [The fix was already provided in Dec 2020](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/pull/670), so it made it to the version `v2.1.4`. The last version `v2.1.3` was released in November. But sadly there is [a bug in pointing the `v2` to the latest `v2.1.4`](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/528) (as normally expected by GitHub Actions users). Therefore to solve this issue, we need to explicitely specifiy the full actions/cache version `v2.1.4` like this:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Set up JDK 1.8
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 1.8
  - name: Cache Maven packages
    uses: actions/cache@v2.1.4
    with:
      path: ~/.m2
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
  - name: Build with Maven
    run: mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots verify
```

Now it should work like a charm ([see logs here](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/runs/2226590004?check_suite_focus=true)).